# Debugging Cramp applications involving server sent events

Tags: ruby, server-sent-events, cramp

Im using Cramp (http://cramp.in) for implementing server-sent events in my application.Im using thin as the server for running the app.In Rails i could use the debugger gem to debug my rails app.Can debugger be used to debug cramp applications as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using the debugger gem in Gemfile insted of ruby-debug19